# Call a method in model after find in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I would like to know if it is possible to call a method from a model after using find.

Something like `after_save`, but `after_find`.

Thank you,
Gabriel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: For Rails >= 3, see the answer from **@nothing-special-here**

There is. Along with `after_initialize`, `after_find` is a special case, though. You have to define the method, `after_find :some_method` isn't enough. This should work, though:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def after_find
    # do something here
  end
end
```

You can read more about it in [the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Answer (score 12):

Nowadays ((26.04.2012) this is proper way (and working!) to do that:

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_find :do_something

  def do_something
    # code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly enough, this will call the method twice... learned that one the hard way.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base     
  after_find :after_find

  def after_find
    # do something here      
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the found object in your method:

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_find{ |o| do_something(o) }

  def do_something(o)
    # ...
  end
end
```

More details here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find